# Items in RecyclewView Adapter are not being shown despite OnBindViewHolder being called

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-constraintlayout, android-viewbinding

I have a fragment which is inside a view pager that has a Recycler View. I have been stuck with the problem that the items on my recycler view are not being shown despite onbindviewholder actually being called. I don't know what could be the problem.

This is the XML of my fragment:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/rv_dishes"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    tools:listitem="@layout/dish_rv_item"
    />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

This is the code of my fragment:

```
class CategoryFragment(val dishes: ArrayList<Dish>):Fragment() {

private val binding by viewBinding(CategoryFragmentBinding::bind)

private val rvAdapter by lazy {
    CategoryRecyclerAdapter()
}

override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater,
    container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View {
    val view = CategoryFragmentBinding.inflate(inflater,container,false)
    return view.root
}

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    setUpRecyclerView()
    rvAdapter.addAll(dishes)
}


private fun setUpRecyclerView(){

    val linearLayoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(activity)
    linearLayoutManager.orientation = LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL
    binding.rvDishes.layoutManager = linearLayoutManager
    binding.rvDishes.adapter = rvAdapter

}

companion object{
    fun newInstance(dishes:ArrayList<Dish>) = CategoryFragment(dishes)
} 
}
```

And finally the code of my adapter:

```
class CategoryRecyclerAdapter(private val dishes:ArrayList<Dish> = ArrayList()): RecyclerView.Adapter<CategoryRecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder>() {


fun addAll(list: List<Dish>){
    dishes.clear()
    list.forEach {
       dishes.add(it)
    }
    notifyDataSetChanged()
}

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
    val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.dish_rv_item,parent,false)
    val binding = DishRvItemBinding.bind(view)
    return ViewHolder(binding)
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
    Log.d("TAG", "binding view holder")
    holder.bindView(dishes[position])
}

override fun getItemCount(): Int = dishes.size

inner class ViewHolder(private val binding: DishRvItemBinding):RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root){

    fun bindView(dish: Dish){
        binding.apply {
            tvDishName.text = dish.name
        }
    }
}
}
```

I have already checked that my list of items is not empty, that the item count is not 0, I have changed the layout height and width of my recycler view to 0dp, match parent and wrap content. I debugged it and the bindView method is called, but I am only getting an empty screen just as you can see here:

[image]

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Did you check your tvDishName view visibility?

Comment: please also share your ViewPager adapter source code and `dish_rv_item.xml` code, there is possibility the problem is in the item layout and the adapter

Comment: try **show layout bounds** in developer options, to see if the views are actually added ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What @hakim posted on the comments made me realize of the problem. As my view pager is inside a BottomSheetDialogFragment, I had to change the XML heights and widths to make it work. So, I changed my BottomSheetDialogFragment's XML to this and it worked like a charm:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat 
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:orientation="vertical">

<com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tab_categories"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
    android:id="@+id/pager_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>
```

When i changed width to match_parent and height to wrap_content I was able to visualize all of the items on the recycler view. Thank you very much to you all for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Your RecyclerView has `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` according to your Fragment XML. But initially RecyclerView is empty, which makes it having zero height. So, you have to change it to `android:layout_height="0dp"` and add `app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"`

Comment: already tried that! didn't work either :(

Comment: I'd recommend you to use Layout Inspector (https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/layout-inspector) to figure out what's happening on the screen with your views